# How to add a tumblr feed into a java swing project

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, feed, launcher

I'm making a launcher for my game using Java Swing. I need a way to add a tumblr/wordpress feed onto the launcher. An example would be the minecraft launcher (If you don't know what it looks like, [go to this link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wd8zcx0021yu9bf/Screenshot%202016-01-18%2017.37.48.png?dl=0)).

I was also thinking RSS could be useful because I've seen that mentioned on feeds and stuff like this so if there's a simple way with that then that'd be helpful too.

Anyway, how would I do this?

EDIT: How would I use jsoup in Swing?

Comment: Just parse the source of the page and display it however you like. You can use regex to parse the necessary data you need.

Comment: Do you know any tutorials on how I'd do that?

Comment: Use a HTML parser of some kind, like [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) for example

Comment: Looks good, how would I use this with Swing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example I have used to parse data from a page

```
private static final String url = "website";

public void getLatestUpdate() throws IOException {
    try {
        URL addr = new URL(url);
        URLConnection con = addr.openConnection();
        ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<span itemprop=.*?</span>");
            Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile(">.*?<");
            Matcher m = p.matcher(inputLine);
            Matcher m2;
            while (m.find()) {
                m2 = p2.matcher(m.group());
                while (m2.find()) {
                    data.add(m2.group().replaceAll("<", "").replaceAll(">", "").replaceAll("&", "").replaceAll("#", "").replaceAll(";", "").replaceAll("3", "3"));
                }
            }
        }
        in.close();
        addr = null;
        con = null;

        message("(" + data.get(3) + ")" + ", at " + data.get(4));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error getting data from website.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: How would I use this?

Comment: It shows you how to open the connection to the url you need. It reads the source page and pulls specific data based on the regex provided.

Comment: Regular expression https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/

Comment: Oh okay I get it, thanks

Comment: Actually one more question, how would I actually get the text off the website (As in which variable in your code is the text which it found)

Comment: Go to the desired page, right click and click inspect source. Look for the text you are trying to parse and then creating the regex is up to you, although if it's a simple tag, it should be fairly similar to mine above.

Comment: No I mean where does the text it found from the website go, like what variable.

Comment: In my example, I add them to the ArrayList<String>

Comment: Oh okay well that should work then!

Comment: We're not living in the dark ages any more, you shouldn't be parsing html by hand, consider using something like [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) instead :P

Comment: It's the learning that counts :)